# AndroidStudio/Java: Set Text depending on condition

Tags: java, android-studio, settext

Trying  in AndroidStudio to change the text (id=version) depending on whether I get true or false from settings.isPremium().

How can I realize that?

settings.isPremium() works fine, I still want to know, how to toggle the text content.

```
if(settings.isPremium()) {

        view.findViewById(R.id.version).setText = "Premium"            

    }
else view.findViewById(R.id.version).setText = "NO Premium"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
 if(settings.isPremium()) 

     ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.version)).setText("Premium"); 
       
else  
     ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.version)).setText("No Premium");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the text of an view by `settext();` hear you need to use it like this.
`view.findViewById(R.id.version).setText("Preminum")`
and use a `Log.v()` function to check if it is changed or not.
`Log.v(<Enter Function Name>,<Enter a string>);`
Hear you can use Log.v() like this.
 `Log.V("Function name",String.valueof(settiings.ispreminum()));`

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I tried it already with "setText("Premium"). Unfortunately getting error "Cannot resolve method 'setText' in 'View'"